# Locking instances with synchronized block inside non-static method

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, synchronized, thread-synchronization

Going by the below code, I have two instances of class A - a1 and a2. And calling the method foo() on both the instances separately.

There is a synchronized block within the foo() method, which is locked on the calling object. Since it is an instance-level locking, both the methods should start executing at the same time because they are getting invoked from two separate instances. But, they are getting executed sequentially.

Is it because, both the instances getting invoked from the same Thread main?

Code changes: Made class A implements Runnable, renamed foo() to run(), forked a thread t from main, invoked a1.run() from main thread, invoked a2.run() from the thread t . Though the two A instances - a1 & a2 are getting called from two threads - main & thread t, the synchronized block(this) seems to be getting locked.

My understanding was the 'this' is referring to the calling Runnable instance which is different and even the threads are different. So, Thread.sleep should not make the other thread blocked. Then, why the two invocation of run's not happening in parallel?

> Expected Output (should execute parallel)

```
main <time> Inside A.run
Thread-0 <time> Inside A.run
Thread-0 <time+4s> Exiting A.run
main <time+5s> Exiting A.run
```

> Actual Output (executing sequentially)

```
main <time> Inside A.run
main <time+5s> Exiting A.run
Thread-0 <time+5s> Inside A.run
Thread-0 <time+9s> Exiting A.run
```

---

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*A a1 = new A(5000); A a2 = new A(4000);
        a1.foo(); a2.foo();*/
        A a1 = new A(5000); A a2 = new A(4000);
        Thread t = new Thread(a2);
        /*a1.run(); t.start();*/
        t.start(); a1.run(); // <-- putting t.start() before a1.run() solves the issue
    }

}

class A implements Runnable {
    public long waitTime;
    public A() {}
    public A(long timeInMs) {
        waitTime = timeInMs;
    }
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            try {
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + formatter.format(time) + " Inside A.run");
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                time = LocalDateTime.now();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + formatter.format(time) + " Exiting A.run");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started to run `a1` synchronously before starting the thread, of course you will get a1's output on the main thread because it won't have been able to reach the thread start statement until a1 is finished.

Try starting the thread running `a2` first before you run `a1` on the main thread, see what you get.

You should also be aware that thread scheduling may be delayed, and calling `Thread#start` does not immediately begin execution on a separate thread, but rather it queues it for the system thread scheduler. You might also want to consider using a synchronization device such as a `CyclicBarrier` in order to coordinate between the thread running `a2` and the main thread running `a1`, else you may *still* get the exact same result even though it appears that you are starting the thread to run `a1` before `a2`.

Comment: Adding t.start() before a1.run() solved the issue. I am now getting the expected output. But, didn't get the concept of synchronization between threads using CyclicBarrier. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because, both the instances getting invoked from the same
>   Thread main?

Yes. Calling Thread.sleep() is synchronous and will block the current thread for the duration unless interrupted. You're directly calling a1.foo() which will block the main thread for the duration, which is the result you're seeing. Create separate threads and call foo() in each of them and you'll see the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Have made edits to the code to call the run methods of the two instances a1 & a2 from two separate threads - main and t. But the result is still same.